# how to read json file into a php array and plot a graph by using this array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

i am able to read a json file into an array and display the output but i want to use that array directly to give it as a input to another php function to plot a graph,

how to read json file into a php array and plot a graph by using this array ?

```
       <?php
         $string = file_get_contents("json.json");
       $example_data=json_decode($string,true);

       foreach ($example_data as $k => $v) {
        echo $k, ' : ', $v;
        }
        ?>
```

but instead of displaying it as an output text, i want to give this example_data as an input array to another php function,

in the above code, instead of declaring the example_data, i want to read it from another json file as i did in the first code, can anyone give me a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though all you need to do is:

```
$string = file_get_contents("json.json");
$example_data=json_decode($string,true);
$plot = new PHPlot();
$plot->SetDataValues($example_data);
```

Unless you JSON file is structured differently to that of the example.

Comment: ok, now i am having difficulty in figuring out the equivalent json array for $example_data, can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to code:

```
<?php
//Include the code
require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/formattool/phplot-6.1.0/phplot.php';

//Define the object
$plot = new PHPlot();

$string = file_get_contents("json.json");
$example_data=json_decode($string,true);
$plot->SetDataValues($example_data);

//Turn off X axis ticks and labels because they get in the way:
$plot->SetXTickLabelPos('none');
$plot->SetXTickPos('none');

//Draw it
$plot->DrawGraph();
?>
```